# How to combine a function with data.table when I make personal R package without error message?

Tags: r, function, data.table, package

I made a function based on data.table R package to handle matrix with duplicates.

I already ran my code in R studio and found it worked properly.
So I made my R package using roxygen2 and devtools R packages.

Unfortunately, it showed following error message if I attached my library and ran the function.

Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'

How should I do to fix the problem?

## Function

```
dup.matrix=function(mm=NA,key_column=NA,my.Function=NA){

  # Check duplicates in key_column

    print('Check duplciates')
    dups=mm[,key_column]
    dups=unique(dups[which(duplicated(dups))])

  # Get duplicated matrix

    print('Check duplciate matrix')
    wh=which(mm[,key_column] %in% dups)
    mm.dup=mm[wh,]
    mm.uniq=as.data.frame(mm[-wh,],stringsAsFactors=F)


  # Apply function to duplicated matrix
    print('Apply function to duplicated matrix')
    mm.dup=as.data.table(mm.dup)
    mm.dup2=mm.dup[,lapply(.SD,my.Function),by=key_column]
    mm.dup2=as.data.frame(mm.dup2,stringsAsFactors=F)
  # combine unique and processed dup matrix
    print('Combine unique and processed dup matrix')
    mm2=rbind(mm.uniq,mm.dup2)
  # Export the results
    gc()
    return(mm2)
}
```

## Example

```
#-----------------------------------------
# Create matrix with duplicates
mat=matrix(rnorm(1000),nrow=100);mat[,1]=paste0('gene',sample(LETTERS,100,replace=T))
colnames(mat)=c('gene',paste0('sample',1:9))
mm=mat;key_column='gene';.function=max

# Run the function
mm2=dup.matrix(mm,key_column,my.Function=.function)
#-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you're trying to make a package, be sure to include all function from other packages with namespace. For example this code didn't run for me until I changed `as.data.table(mm.dup)` to `data.table::as.data.table(mm.dup)`. Afterwards this ran without a problem for me

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Julian_Hn. Did you make your package and attach it to run the code? Even if I added data.table::as.data.table(mm.dup), it still display error message when I loaded the function via my package.

Comment: No. I didn't want to go through making a completly new package. Does the code run for you outside the package?

Comment: Are you aware there is `duplicated.matrix`? See `?duplicated.matrix`

Comment: This cide does not work outside a package: ` Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match`.

Comment: Thank you for ur comment JRR, I solved the problem. According to Julian_Hn's suggestion, I wroted import(data.table) in Namespace. It solved my problem.

Comment: @MichaelChirico thank u for ur comment, it looks nice function thanks.

Comment: See also [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html) vignette on using `data.table` in your own project (and creating downstream projects in general)

Comment: what is the content of your NAMESPACE file related to data.table?